# Delphi errors on Remote Desktop Server

Tags: delphi, terminal-server

Are there any logging/trace tools that I can enable for a Delphi-based EXE without having access to the Delphi code, just the compiled EXE and related DLLs?

Here is why I need it: some users of our Windows 2012 Remote Desktop Server (previously called Terminal Server) encounter C0000006 External Exception errors periodically, but only for our third-party Delphi-based applications that are accessed from a shared location on the network (i.e. not local to the RDS server). Local PC users in the office accessing the same files the same way do not have the problem. RDS users do not experience the problem if the EXEs are copied to the RDS server; that, however, is just a test, and not the solution, due to some constraints of the application.

Here is the kicker: it happens only with RDS clients running on the Mac (about six users), not Windows RDS clients (about 15 users).

I already posted a detailed but as-yet unanswered question on the MS terminal server forum. My research indicates that this behaviour is nothing new.

1. Windows 2000 had a fix for a problem with the same symptom that was related to Windows being confused regarding which client session had a particular program open.
2. Even as recently as Windows 2008, there are Delphi-specific network access issues on RDS related to the way it loads portions of EXEs/DLLs on demand, rather than one time when opening the application. I infer that, while the symptoms are the same, the underlying cause must be somewhat different.

So, while I await the prognosis of the third-party developers, I am trying to find out if there is any way I can set up a trace of activity, either Delphi-specific or perhaps even network-related, that can tell me the moments when a particular session accesses a particular network file. This, at least, could possibly help me identify events that correlate with the moments the users experience the errors.

Comment: AFAIK, If the EXE was built in `release` mode, then debug info was most likely not compiled with it. Although there may be some magical tool which I'm not aware of which can go into that type of detail, but probably on an assembly level. Even if the EXE did have debug info included, it would still be tough to actually perform a debug without just running the original source in debug mode. Unless you know assembly, the optimal option would be to debug the original source. Unless of course the application was designed with a logger, in which case that's another story.

Comment: If you are interested in monitoring file or I/O acces then I strongly recomend you try using Prcoess Monitor from Sysinternals (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Now I must admit that I haven't tried using this on RDS client but I still think it should work.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any program specific logging because the error is more fundamental, and unrelated to any programming language. That is a native API error code, an [NTSTATUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc704588.aspx) value, specifically `STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR`.

These are low-level errors indicating a fundamental problem with the virtual memory system. Virtual memory pages can be stored on disk when physical memory is not available. For executable modules, if the system knows that a page is held on disk, and that page can be discarded, the system will do so knowing that the page can be retrieved later. Sometimes the page has never even been loaded into memory. Executable modules are paged in on demand.

The `STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR` error indicates that the virtual memory system failed to bring a page in to memory. It's rare for that to fail when the executable file is local. Less rare when the executable file is remote.

The standard way to deal with this is to add the `IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP` PE flag to any modules that live remotely. What happens then is that the loader first copies the entire file to swap, held locally, and then loads the executable from there. Because the swap file is local it is less like to have page in faults. You could apply the PE flag yourself to trial this. It seems likely to work because you already commented that the problem is resolved when the files are copied to be local.

It's plausible that there are system wide policies to make this happen for all remote executables.

Comment: David: thank you. Is setting that flag something I can do, not being the Delphi developer? Note also, though, that this does not happen when running the apps on PCs in the LAN where the EXEs are hosted, only to users running them on the terminal server in that LAN, even though all access the EXEs from the same network location. And then it affects only the Delphi-based apps and only for those users those using the Mac RDP client. My ultimate goal is not to try to find a workaround; it is to identify what, in the combination of Delphi and the Mac RDP client, is causing the problem.